# Почему меняется время, в которое происходит автоматическое резервное копирование в 1С?

Tags: время, 1с, резервное-копирование

1С:Предприятие 8.3 (8.3.15.1958)
Розница 8. Салон оптики, редакция 2.2 (2.2.5.23)

У нас настроено автоматическое резервное копирование на каждый день в 8:00. Однако по факту оно происходит в 10 с чем-то(минуты тоже меняются). Было пару раз в 8 с чем-то. Проблема в том, что копирование выпадает в итоге на рабочее время. Я могу, конечно, поставить время на 3:00 и надеяться, что не выпадет процесс на рабочее время, но все же хотелось бы понять в чем дело.

UPD:
[image: Настройка резервного копирования]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а часовой пояс там есть?

Comment: Покажите настройки скриншотами.

Comment: @Sagittarius добавил

Comment: @Эникейщик где именно? На компьютере есть. +6

Comment: ну где у вас там 1с стоит? на сервере, компьютере еще где-нибудь Сравните правильно ли выставлен часовой пояс и вообще настройки времени разные

Comment: А точно 1С в 8:00 работает? )

Comment: @AnuarAssylbekov, логи ЖР (журнал регистрации) не смотрели?